# What is the right option for the sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Mayot had a horrible surprise when she _____________her e-mail that morning.

Select one:

- a) has checked
- b) checked
- c) had checked

I have chosen c) and got it wrong.

Comment: I'll go for B).

Comment: With (c) it would have to be 'Mayot _had had_ a horrible surprise'

Comment: It's B. The options should have included, "was checking" too.